# Why is average disk seek time one-third of the full seek time?

Tags: file-io, io, hard-drive

I have read in many books and papers, considering disk performance, that the average seek time is roughly one-third of the full seek time, but no one really offers any explanation about that. Where does this come from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The average is calculated mathematically using calculus.
We use the very basic formula for calculation of average.

Average seek time = (Sum of all possible seek times)/(Total no. of possible seek times)

The disk is assumed to have N number of tracks, so that these are numbered from 1...N
The position of the head at any point of time can be anything from 0 to N (inclusive).
Let us say that the initial position of the disk head is at track 'x' and the final position of the disk head is at track 'y' , so that x can vary from 0 to N and also, y can vary from 0 to N.

On similar lines as we defined average seek time, we can say that,

Average seek distance = (Sum of all possible seek distances)/(total no. of possible seek distances)

By definition of x and y,
Total no. of possible seek distances = N*N
and
Sum of all possible seek distances = SIGMA(x=0,N) SIGMA(y=0,N) |x-y|
= INTEGRAL(x=0,N)INTEGRAL(y=0,N) |x-y| dy dx

To solve this, use the technique of splitting modulus of the expression for y = 0 to x and for y = x to N. Then solve for x = 0 to N.

This comes out to be (N^3)/3.

Avg seek distance = (N^3)/3*N*N = N/3

Average seek time = Avg seek distance / seek rate

If the seek time for the from position 0 to track N takes 't' seconds then seek rate = N/t

Therefore, avg seek time = (N/3)/(N/t) = t/3

Reference:

http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSFEP/file-disks.pdf
Page-9 gives a very good answer to this.

Comment: Answers which just contain links are [considered bad practice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please summarize the content here (don't copy/paste) so the answer can stand on its own. If you don't you run the risk of your answer being removed, especially if the link ever dies.

Comment: Actually, this analysis assumes that the probability that the source/target on each track is the same ⟺ the amount of data is the same over all tracks, *however* because of zone bit recording https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector it might be different so the actual value may be slightly less (to the best of my knowledge.).