# How is Average Seek Time Calculated?

Tags: file, filesystems, seek

A hard disk system has the following parameters :

```
Number of tracks = 500
Number of sectors/track = 100
Number of bytes /sector = 500
Time taken by the head to move from one track to adjacent track = 1 ms
Rotation speed = 600 rpm.
```

What is the average time taken for transferring 250 bytes from the disk ?

Well I wanted to know **How the average seek time is calculated ?**

**My Approach**

Avg. time to transfer = Avg. seek time + Avg. rotational delay + Data transfer time

**Avg Seek Time**

given that : time to move between successive tracks is 1 ms

time to move from track 1 to track 1 : 0ms

time to move from track 1 to track 2 : 1ms

time to move from track 1 to track 3 : 2ms

..

..

time to move from track 1 to track 500 : 499 ms

Avg Seek time =[image]
                         = 249.5 ms

But After Reading Answer given here  [Why is average disk seek time one-third of the full seek time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828736)

Im confused with my approach.

**My question is**

Is my Approach Correct ?

- If not Please explain the correct way to calculate Average seek time
- If Yes please explain wh we are not considering average for every possible pair of tracks (as mentioned in the above link)?

Comment: First, the question you link to is using confusing vocabulary.  It should be "Why is average seek time 1/3 of the full *seek* time."   Your approach to calculating average seek time assumes that you are on track 0.  Intuitively, the average seek time , *given that you are on track 0*, is half the full seek time.  But what if you were on the middle track?  The worst case if you are on the middle track is 1/2 the full seek time, and the average is 1/4 the full seek time.  If you average over all possible places you can start, you get 1/3 the full seek time.

Answer (score 4):

There are a *lot* more than 500 possible seek times.  Your method only accounts for seeks starting at track 1.

What about seeks starting from track 2?  Or from track 285?

I wouldn't say your approach is wrong, but it's certainly incomplete.

Comment: Please answer to my questions .

Answer (score 1):

As is pointed out in the link you're reffering to in this question the average time is calculated as average distance from ANY track to ANY track. So you have to add all of the Subsums to the one you are using to calculate average seek time and then divide this sum by the number of tracks. It sums out to: N/3, where N is the distance between track 0 and last.
f.eg. average distance from track 249 to ANY other track is:[middle average sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwKkq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is the average **track seek**, you need to add the **sector seek** to that.

When seeking for a read operation, the head is positioned on (a) a track, at a given (b) sector.
The (average) **seek time** is the time taken to switch to that position to any other position, with both (a) track and (b) sector.

When positioned, the read can start.

The disk RPM is into play for this, if it spins at 600rpm and has 100 sectors per track, it means that it seeks sectors at

```
60000ms (because rpm = per minute)
/
600rpm (disk spin speed)
/
100sectors (per track)
=
1ms (to change from a sector to the next adjacent one)
```

Normally, you would have to consider that as you change tracks, the disk is still spinning and thus account for the sector offset change. But since we are interested only in the average, this cancels out (hopefully).

So, to your **249.5 ms** for the track seek average time, you need to add :

same formula :

```
sum 0->100/100 * 1ms (sector seek speed) =  50.5ms
```

Thus, the average seek speed for both track and sector is **300ms**.